Errors crash the local development django cookie-cutter container
I've setup Django cookie-cutter for local development in Docker. It all works fine, even with VSCode devcontainer, changes are tracked and reloaded until there's a syntax or some other error. Then the entire container exits with code 1, which launches a cascade of errors in other containers that manage to stay alive while the django container remains dead :(
It's all pretty much a generic django cookie cutter install with a few changes like:

compose/local/django/start changed to:


exec python manage.py runserver_plus --reloader-interval 3
--reloader-type stat 0.0.0.0:8000


watchdog dropped from local requirement, changed to:


Werkzeug==3.0.3

Any hints how to reload changes, log errors but keep the container and server alive?
Here's the container log for reference:
2024-07-10 13:57:55 Operations to perform:
2024-07-10 13:57:55   Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, django_celery_beat, mfa, sessions, sites, socialaccount, users
2024-07-10 13:57:55 Running migrations:
2024-07-10 13:57:55   No migrations to apply.
2024-07-10 13:57:55   Your models in app(s): 'core' have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
2024-07-10 13:57:55   Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
2024-07-10 13:58:01 Performing system checks...
2024-07-10 13:58:01 
2024-07-10 13:58:01 System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
2024-07-10 13:58:01 
2024-07-10 13:58:01 Django version 4.2.13, using settings 'config.settings.local'
2024-07-10 13:58:01 Development server is running at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
2024-07-10 13:58:01 Using the Werkzeug debugger (https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/)
2024-07-10 13:58:01 Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2024-07-10 13:57:42 PostgreSQL is available
2024-07-10 13:57:42 /start: line 1: local: can only be used in a function
2024-07-10 13:57:59 WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
2024-07-10 13:57:59  * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
2024-07-10 13:57:59  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000
2024-07-10 13:57:59  * Running on http://172.18.0.7:8000
2024-07-10 13:57:59 Press CTRL+C to quit
2024-07-10 13:57:59  * Restarting with stat
2024-07-10 13:58:02  * Debugger is active!
2024-07-10 13:58:02  * Debugger PIN: 146-133-257
2024-07-10 13:58:37 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:58:37] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2024-07-10 13:58:37 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:58:37] "GET /static/css/project.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2024-07-10 13:58:37 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:58:37] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2024-07-10 13:58:37 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:58:37] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/print.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2024-07-10 13:58:37 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:58:37] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2024-07-10 13:58:37 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:58:37] "GET /static/js/project.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2024-07-10 13:58:37 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:58:37] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/utils.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2024-07-10 13:58:37 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:58:37] "GET /static/images/favicons/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2024-07-10 13:58:50  * Detected change in '/app/core/templates/core/idx.html', reset template loaders
2024-07-10 13:59:03 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:59:03] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2024-07-10 13:59:03 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:59:03] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/toolbar.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2024-07-10 13:59:03 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:59:03] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/toolbar.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2024-07-10 13:59:03 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:59:03] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/css/print.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2024-07-10 13:59:03 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:59:03] "GET /static/css/project.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2024-07-10 13:59:03 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:59:03] "GET /static/js/project.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2024-07-10 13:59:03 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:59:03] "GET /static/debug_toolbar/js/utils.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2024-07-10 13:59:03 172.18.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2024 13:59:03] "GET /static/images/favicons/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -
2024-07-10 13:59:27  * Detected change in '/app/core/models.py', reloading
2024-07-10 13:59:27  * Restarting with stat
2024-07-10 13:59:31 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-07-10 13:59:31   File "/app/manage.py", line 32, in <module>
2024-07-10 13:59:31     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
2024-07-10 13:59:31   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
2024-07-10 13:59:31     utility.execute()
2024-07-10 13:59:31   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
2024-07-10 13:59:31     django.setup()
2024-07-10 13:59:31   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2024-07-10 13:59:31     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2024-07-10 13:59:31   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
2024-07-10 13:59:31     app_config.import_models()
2024-07-10 13:59:31   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
2024-07-10 13:59:31     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
2024-07-10 13:59:31                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-07-10 13:59:31   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
2024-07-10 13:59:31     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-07-10 13:59:31            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-07-10 13:59:31   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
2024-07-10 13:59:31   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
2024-07-10 13:59:31   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-07-10 13:59:31   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
2024-07-10 13:59:31   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
2024-07-10 13:59:31   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-07-10 13:59:31   File "/app/core/models.py", line 8, in <module>
2024-07-10 13:59:31     dksfj
2024-07-10 13:59:31 NameError: name 'dksfj' is not defined


Is there any particular reason to use Docker?  Both Linux and MacOS systems come with a Python preinstalled, and if you need a non-default Python version then tools like pyenv or Hatch can install one for you.  Any of these setups will avoid Docker's filesystem isolation that on the one hand prevents your host system from directly running python and on the other prevents the container from seeing local-file changes.

Ultimately, I'm deploying a bunch of containers (django app, postgres, redis, celery worker, celery beat, flower etc.) into production and it makes a lot of sense to keep my dev environment as close and as os agnostic as possible.

You can run, for example, PostgreSQL and Redis in containers, and use a local Python to develop against that.  Python has a lot of tools for managing a consistent interpreter and library stack (pyenv, tox, Hatch, ...) that don't require the full isolation that a Docker setup brings.
